# Intersection of polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am not familiar with algebraic geometry, so I was wondering if someone could explain this principle ---

Suppose we have an algebraic variety $V$ of codimension $d$, and a polynomial $g$. We want to find the intersection of $V$ and $g(x) = 0$.

I would like to say that this is either $V$ itself, or the union of finitely many varieties of dimension $d+1$, and that the number and degree of these irreducible components is bounded in terms of the degrees of $g$ and $V$. Is there a general Bezout theorem which gives this kind of description?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, what you want to say is completely correct (except for the typo "dimension d+1" where you meant "codimension d+1"). Look in Joe Harris' introductory book on algebraic geometry for the appropriate Bezout theorem.